# Any reason to use [customclasses]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I just see [this approved review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5143119) that only adds [customclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customclasses) to the question.

[customclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customclasses) does not have wiki summary, has 0 followers and 112 questions. I cannot think of any reason to use [customclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customclasses) because almost all OOP code is about custom classes and we are not going to add it to all these questions.

It does not add any more information to the question and need to be burned.

Comment: I would argue that the vast majority of tag only edits is robo approved, so don't read anything into that.

Comment: eliminate the "customclasses" tag

Comment: The only legit(?) use-case I can think of is to mean an implementation of classes in prototypical languages & co. In this case the classes are "custom", because you have built the whole mechanism from scratch. However there may be better matches for this.

Comment: It is a useless tag, even Jon Skeet has only 13 scores in it. :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are no longer any questions with this tag.

Answer (score 22):

I hate to write the obvious, but I would suggest to burn it for the reasons you have raised unless someone can find any use of it, in which case it should probably be renamed.

In general, the tag feature is sometimes abused on SE IMHO.